# SQL Server 2008 Creation of view that is extracting multi-row into multi-column (phone a/b/c fax for joe)

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, multiple-columns

Okay data is in a phone table which has column for all numbers column for type of number they are and a `contactid` for whom they relate to.

I need to strip it into a single row per contact eg.

```
George phone# fax# mobile# altphone# homephone# ext#
```

I can query and get it to work by itself, but if I add to massive query it screws it up, not sure why, so view seemed like good alternative. code follows

```
create view phonebreakn as
   select 
      TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID as contactid,
      TBL_CONTACT.LASTNAME as lastname,
      (select tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE AS 'tphone' 
       where left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='C3AE'),
      (select tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE AS 'fax' 
       where left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='2870'),
      (select tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE AS 'mphone' 
       where left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='511D'),
      (select tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE AS 'aphone' 
       where left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='C795'),
      (select tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE AS 'hphone' 
       where left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='2B7C'),
      (select tbl_phone.SUFFIX AS 'pext' 
       where left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='C3AE')
   from 
      TBL_CONTACT
   left join 
      TBL_PHONE on TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID = TBL_PHONE.CONTACTID
   where 
      CATEGORY like '%Customer%'
```

Error is

> Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure phonebreakn, Line 3
>   Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 3.

I will try to figure out how to use this stupid interface so it looks the way I put it in, but for now I am under the gun and need help

Comment: All your subqueries are missing a `from` clause ...

Comment: @marc_s - Which is potentially valid as it has the same semantics as `CASE WHEN left(tbl_phone.TYPEID,4)='C3AE' THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE END`

Answer (score 0):

You've applied the column alias to the inner subquery not the column name exposed at the outer level.

Keeping with your odd way of writing this the way to fix it would be to move the column aliases out.

```
CREATE VIEW phonebreakn
AS
  SELECT TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID                       AS contactid,
         TBL_CONTACT.LASTNAME                        AS lastname,
         (SELECT tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
          WHERE  LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C3AE') AS tphone,
         (SELECT tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
          WHERE  LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '2870') AS fax,
         (SELECT tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE 
          WHERE  LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '511D') AS mphone,
         (SELECT tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
          WHERE  LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C795') AS aphone,
         (SELECT tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
          WHERE  LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '2B7C') AS hphone,
         (SELECT tbl_phone.SUFFIX
          WHERE  LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C3AE') AS pext
  FROM   TBL_CONTACT
         LEFT JOIN TBL_PHONE
           ON TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID = TBL_PHONE.CONTACTID
  WHERE  CATEGORY LIKE '%Customer%'
```

Though a more readily understandable rewrite would use CASE

```
CREATE VIEW phonebreakn
AS
  SELECT TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID AS contactid,
         TBL_CONTACT.LASTNAME  AS lastname,
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C3AE'
             THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
         END                   AS tphone,
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '2870'
             THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
         END                   AS fax,
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '511D'
             THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
         END                   AS mphone,
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C795'
             THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
         END                   AS aphone,
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '2B7C'
             THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
         END                   AS hphone,
         CASE
           WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C3AE'
             THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
         END                   AS pext
  FROM   TBL_CONTACT
         LEFT JOIN TBL_PHONE
           ON TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID = TBL_PHONE.CONTACTID
  WHERE  CATEGORY LIKE '%Customer%'
```

And perhaps what you really needed is a cross tab type query

```
CREATE VIEW phonebreakn
AS
  SELECT TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID AS contactid,
         TBL_CONTACT.LASTNAME  AS lastname,
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C3AE'
                 THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
             END)              AS tphone,
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '2870'
                 THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
             END)              AS fax,
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '511D'
                 THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
             END)              AS mphone,
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C795'
                 THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
             END)              AS aphone,
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = '2B7C'
                 THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
             END)              AS hphone,
         MAX(CASE
               WHEN LEFT(tbl_phone.TYPEID, 4) = 'C3AE'
                 THEN tbl_phone.NUMBERVALUE
             END)              AS pext
  FROM   TBL_CONTACT
         LEFT JOIN TBL_PHONE
           ON TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID = TBL_PHONE.CONTACTID
  WHERE  CATEGORY LIKE '%Customer%'
  GROUP  BY TBL_CONTACT.CONTACTID,
            TBL_CONTACT.LASTNAME
```